# como fazer comunicação com aplicações desktop?

Tags: c#, arquitetura-de-software, redes, projeto-de-software

como projeto da faculdade, estamos elaborando um programa para gerenciar os projetos para quem trabalha *home office*. Estou com dúvida de como posso criar uma interatividade, por exemplo, para que o gerente do projeto analise os resultados dos programadores remotamente?

Quero uma forma para que o gerente acompanhe os resultados que são preenchidos no meu software em c#, como fazer isso?

Comment: Tem várias coisas que você precisa definir antes. Por exemplo, o que seria essa interatividade? Esse modelo do que você quer partiu de algo que você imaginou ou já existe alguma coisa pronta em algum lugar? Antes é preciso alguma discussão antes de partirmos para perguntas.

Comment: Foi a ideia de nosso grupo , quero ter uma ideia de como seria a criação da   arquitetura com esse tipo de comunicação .

Comment: Olha, no seu lugar, eu faria usando MVVM e XAML, já que é Desktop. Esses controles interativos teriam que ser alimentados por outro sistema. As requisições podem ser feitas usando Web API 2. Neste caso seriam dois projetos: um usando XAML e outro usando ASP.NET MVC Web API 2.

Comment: Ok , obrigado pela atenção .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basicamente, se você precisa que o gerente acesse os dados dos colaboradores de maneira segura, é imprescindível que haja algum método de autenticação baseado em servidores (Web, FTP para puxar ou enviar os dados, etc). Existem várias possibilidades para tanto, vou exemplificar a mais simples

Crie ou no gerente ou em um servidor hospedado um banco de dados, onde cada empregado possa salvar as informações deste software em C# diretamente neste banco, ou on-line (sempre que uma alteração for feita) ou off-line (o empregado determina a hora que ele for atualizar), esta escolha depende se o empregado estará sempre conectado ou não. Desta maneira o gerente teria sempre as informações disponíveis de uma maneira mais eficiente e segura, pois ele não teria de ficar conectando-se a várias máquinas diferentes, não sendo necessário configurar diversas máquinas e sair abrindo portas para acesso nestes computadores.

Outra opção seria criar um site com uma aplicação .NET onde os empregados acessam a aplicação por este site e trabalham diretamente por ela, e o gerente teria uma página um pouco diferente podendo visualizar as informações de todos, possibilitando tanto que os clientes e gerentes acessem este sistema de qualquer computador, apenas autenticando-se a ele.

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Muito Bom Obrigado !